# My minimal ASP.NET Core Web API returns error 405: Method not allowed

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, minimal-apis

I want to update a record by calling my api endpoint using the put verb but his returns error 405 method not allowed.

My api endpoint:

```
app.MapPut("/sirs/{Id}", async (int Id, SIRCContext db, Sir sirc) =>
{
    var record = await db.Sirs.FindAsync(Id);

    if (record is null) 
         return Results.NotFound();

    record.ActionTaken = sirc.ActionTaken;
    record.Status = sirc.Status;
    record.ResolvedDate = sirc.ResolvedDate;
    record.FurtherActionRequired = sirc.FurtherActionRequired;
  
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.NoContent();
});
```

My client code:

```
public async Task UpdateSIRC(int id, Sir sirc)
{
    try
    {
        await SetAuthToken();
        var response = await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"/sirs/{id}", sirc);//Error here
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        statusMessage = "Update Successful";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        statusMessage = "Failed to update data.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the endpoint via postman or another similar tool?

Comment: Yes, It works well on when tested on swagger

Comment: How do you create `_httpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that adding the below to web.config works. The api was only working in debug mode and not when deployed to IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```